# Using Lodash to transform data into object properties instead of a collection by specifying properties value

Tags: javascript, lodash

following up on my previous question about transforming data using lodash, this time i require output to be an object properties instead of being a collection. I appreciate the help and if someone can also guide me where to begin properly so i have a better understanding of these concepts

**Sample Data**

```
{
  "changeAccount": {
      "add": [
        {
          "changeType": 1,
          "type": "changeAccount",
          "updated": {
            "id": 71,
            "company": 124201,
            "user": 8622
          }
        }
      ],
      "remove": [
        {
          "changeType": 2,
          "type": "changeAccount",
          "updated": {
            "id": 70,
            "company": 124201,
            "user": 8622
          }
        }
      ]
    
  },
  "changeproduct": {

      "add": [
        {
          "changeType": 1,
          "type": "changeproduct",
          "updated": {
            "id": 15,
            "company": 124201,
            "user": 8622
          }
        }
      ],
      "remove": []
    }
  
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
var sample = [{
  "changeType": 1,
  "type": "changeAccount",
  "updated": {
    "id": 71,
    "company": 124201,
    "user": 8622
  }
},
  {
    "changeType": 2,
    "type": "changeAccount",
    "updated": {
      "id": 70,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  },
  {
    "changeType": 1,
    "type": "changeproduct",
    "updated": {
      "id": 15,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
chain(data)
    .values()
    .map(_.values)
    .flatMapDeep()
    .value()
```

So what's happening here is:

1. Start with our data which is an object
2. Use .[values](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#values) to return only the values of our top level properties (i.e. strip away `changeProduct` and `changeAccount`
3. Map the resulting items in the array to only the values of our objects (i.e. strip away `add` and `remove`) using .[values](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#values) again
4. Flatten the entire array recursively so we end up with an array that is one level deep using .[flatMapDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#flatMapDeep)

You might also notice the `chain(data)` syntax, this is just a way to improve the readability and sometimes performance of your lodash code, so that you don't have to nest each lodash function that you use. Check out the docs on [chain](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chain) for more info.

Comment: please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923721/converting-lodash-groupby-object-array-into-object-object-property

Comment: I can't comment on that question until I get more reputation. I would like to ask if you could provide your original data, i.e. the "changes" object.

Also, did this one help you? Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer if so? Thanks.